# JTextPane, StyledDocument: setting caret position from raw input index

Tags: java, html, swing, awt, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane with html content I'm loading from a file. Some comments tags are placeholders and I want to insert components just before them. I'm finding theses tags using a regex matcher and I can get the index of theses tags with matcher.start(). The problem is I can't place the caret position to the index of the html tag because the caret position is expecting a user-interface caret. Tags are ignored and images counts for only one carets. So I need a way to insert a component at a specified index.

Here's my code.

```
package me.winter.trapgame.client.menu;

import me.winter.trapgame.client.ResourceManager;
import me.winter.trapgame.client.SimpleLayout;
import me.winter.trapgame.server.TrapGameServer;
import me.winter.trapgame.util.ColorTransformer;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * <p>A pane displayed when clicked the button "How to play" in the menu</p>
 *
 * <p>Created by Alexander Winter on 2016-04-20.</p>
 */
public class TutorialPane extends JPanel
{

    private TrapGameMenu menu;

    public TutorialPane(TrapGameMenu menu)
    {
        try
        {
            this.menu = menu;

            JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane()
            {
                @Override
                public void paint(Graphics graphics)
                {
                    Graphics2D g2draw = (Graphics2D)graphics;

                    g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                    g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                    g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

                    g2draw.drawImage(menu.getClient().getResourceManager().getImage("background"), -TutorialPane.this.getX() - getX(), -TutorialPane.this.getY() - getY(), menu.getClient().getWidth(), menu.getClient().getHeight(), null);

                    g2draw.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 20));
                    g2draw.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), getWidth() / 8, getHeight() / 8);

                    super.paint(graphics);
                }
            };

            setBackground(ColorTransformer.TRANSPARENT);
            textPane.setBackground(ColorTransformer.TRANSPARENT);

            textPane.setContentType("text/html");
            textPane.setEditable(false);

            ResourceManager res = menu.getClient().getResourceManager();

            String page = res.getText("tutorial-page-" + menu.getClient().getLang().getName());
            page = page.replace("<!--style-->", res.getText("tutorial-style"));

            textPane.setText(page);
            Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<!--([^<>]+)-->");

            Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(page);


            while(matcher.find() && !matcher.hitEnd())
            {
                Image image;

                switch(matcher.group(1).toLowerCase())
                {
                    case "blank_button":
                        image = res.getImage("game-button");
                        break;

                    case "color_button":
                        BufferedImage button = (BufferedImage)res.getImage("game-button");
                        image = new BufferedImage(button.getWidth(), button.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

                        Graphics2D g2draw = ((BufferedImage)image).createGraphics();

                        g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                        g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                        g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

                        g2draw.setColor(new ColorTransformer(TrapGameServer.COLORS[0], 200));
                        g2draw.fillRoundRect(0, 0, button.getWidth(), button.getHeight(), button.getWidth() / 4, button.getHeight() / 4);
                        g2draw.drawImage(button, 0, 0, button.getWidth(), button.getHeight(), null);

                        g2draw.dispose();
                        break;

                    default:
                        image = null;
                }

                textPane.setCaretPosition(matcher.start());
                if(image != null)
                    textPane.insertComponent(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
            }

            setLayout(new SimpleLayout());
            add(textPane, SimpleLayout.constraints(8, 9, 0.25, 0.75, 7.5, 7.5));
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
        catch(Throwable debug)
        {
            debug.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        Graphics2D g2draw = (Graphics2D) graphics;

        g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

        g2draw.drawImage(menu.getClient().getResourceManager().getImage("background"), -getX(), 0, menu.getClient().getWidth(), menu.getClient().getHeight(), null);

        super.paint(graphics);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: Thank you I will change this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is not the best approach. I would use an element with ID as a place holder. Then, I would use HtmlDocument.getElement to get the place holder element, and then Element.getElementStart to get the "user interface" position.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is I can't place the caret position to the index of the html tag because the caret position is expecting a user-interface caret.

```
int offset = textpane.modelToView(modelOffset);
textPane.setCaretPosition( offset );
```